# insufficient memory error but i having enough memory

Tags: google-play-store, 5.0-lollipop, insufficient-memory

Although I have 500 mb space left on my android lollypop internal memory, When I try to install or upgrade any of the apps I got a message that your memory is full.

How can I sort out this problem? I have searched for this problem a number of times but nothing helped, Please any body sort this problem.

Currently I am using lenovo a2010 model.

Comment: Have you checked with our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) already? We've collected useful hints there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the specs](http://www.gsmarena.com/lenovo_a2010-7507.php), the A2010 comes with 8GB internal storage. Taking a look into our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info) tells me that error is thrown when there's less than 10% free space in internal storage. 10% of 8 GB are ~800MB – your free space, as pointed out in your question, is 500 MB. So sorry to contradict you, but no: you really don't have "enough memory".

As for solutions, please check with the very same source (our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info)), which contains some first-aid hints and links. We've collected that there as this is a question asked frequently on our site.

Comment: Sorry to contradict you ,but in my phone I have got only 4 GB space.

Comment: I've just looked up the specs as you didn't specify :) Same thing, though: error gets triggered *around* 10%, so that's ~400MB then. You didn't specify what apps you've tried, but as soon as the size of those reaches ~50MB you are sure to trigger the threshold, as you must at least double the size of that: the (1) download must be (2) installed. (1) won't be deleted before the entire process is finished. The 10% are just a default which the ROM creator might have modified, so it's just an estimate/guideline/rule-of-thumb.

Comment: the apps i am downloading or updating are around  10 - 20 mb but still then are not taking place. Is there any way to install apps in memory card?

Comment: As I wrote: the 10% are a "rule of thumb", and your device is definitely scratching that. As comments are not for discussions, I won't discuss this here further; please check with the linked tag-wiki, details can be found there. As for installing on SD card: That's a different question, and has been answered here already multiple times. In short: the apps *and* your device must support that, or your device must be rooted. Be welcome to use our site's [search](/search?q=install+sd+card+default+answers%3A1).

Answer (score 1):

There comes a great feature to solve this problem,
You can change your primary storage card from internal to external SD card 
In order to this, 
 **Step 1**  
Go to "settings"
 **Step 2**  
Select "Storage" 
 **Step 3**  
Select "Default storage location" 
 **Step 4**  
Choose External SD card 
 **Note:**  This feature is **special** because mostly many apps can't be moved to SD card (like Google products), so by changing default storage location, the result will be APP's **main** resources will be in internal but **rest** in external SD card which saves a lot of storage. (I did it).
**Some extra tips:** Also change default storage location (this option available in few apps) like in camera, google offline maps, youtube offline videos etc. And don't install a junk cleaner app, they are useless cause more harm then helpful.
*Hope, this solves your problem.*

Comment: Also remember the 'cache' under storage settings, it does empty lots of space.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to do the below ones.

- change your setting --> storage --> from internal to external SD
  card. At times, after reboot the system takes the internal as default
  memory.
- Download [appmgr 3](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.a0soft.gphone.app2sd)  from google play store and follow below steps or documentation.

This will help you to select multiple apps at once to be moved to external sd card.

I had similar problem but I have documented the steps. Please check out [my documentation](https://tjosepraveenblog.wordpress.com/2015/10/02/easy-steps-couldnt-move-app-not-enough-storage-space-problem-solved/).

If you get stuck, feel free to comment.

Answer (score -2):

Go to device storage and clear the cache memory.